# IIS caching with SQL server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, caching, iis

I wrote both BackEnd and FrontEnd of my web application using c# in visual studio 2015. I am using IIS 8.5 in Windows Server 2012R2 for hotsing (BackEnd and FrontEnd).

I have a caching problem. many times the database changes (threw using my web app or even if I want to edit some info manually), but the information shown in my website is not updated. I think this is a caching problem with my IIS but even after disabling all caching the problem still occurs. Only in case of a IIS reset  the info in my web is updated.

for example:

changed the value in my sql database:

[image: sql value manual change]

The value that shows in my web page(old value): [image]

doing an IIS reset and the web page will show 2 as needed.

[image]

any ideas what causing this problem?

ps: even after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> refresh it wont change.

Comment: Did you disable caching in your Browser aswell?

Comment: @JoachimGotzes even with ctrl+F5 its shows the same.

Comment: Does your backend cache the data it reads from the database?

Comment: @Mahdi I disabled all the output caching in my IIS.

Comment: What do you get if you change url e.g. using a random querystring? For example, if your page is page.aspx - call page.aspx, ensure what value it shows, then call page.aspx?1234. If you still get the old value, it means it is not a client/browser cache but something else.

Comment: @2316116 getting the old value with page.aspx?1234 call.

Comment: I'd suggest you do a plain text test script e.g. aubrett.com/InformationTechnology/SQL/TestSQLConnection.aspx that can proof if you have a cache or not.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?